# Using JMeter 5.4.1 recording .Net application gets either wrong response or Error response Code: 500

Tags: jmeter

Using:
JMeter version 5.4.1
Browsers:
MS Edge 94.0
Google Chrome: 94.0
FireFox: 92.0.1
Using JMeter to record .Net application. 90% of the recording was perfectly fine. no page crashed and received the response correctly. Except, when I made any requests that related to permission.aspx or permission.asp page I got error message have shown below or wrong response content displayed on the page.
I did try to change the record type from httpclient4 to Java but it didn't help.

Also Error log from JMeter log showed: `Cause: java.io.IOExeption: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://xxxx.xx.xx.com/`

```
USERID:
ASP.Net EXCEPTION:
StatusCode:
200
Error Message:
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Inner Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question provide sufficient level of details so I doubt you will get a comprehensive answer, it looks like JMeter isn't capable of handling some specific setup of your application.

In order to get more information you could:

1. Increase [logging level verbosity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
   ```

   then inspect *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries
2. Check your application logs as [HTTP 5xx errors are **server-side errors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses) so most probably the reason can be found there

You might also want to try out an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) which is kind of less "invasive" and "alien" to the browser than JMeter's proxy server.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your response and recommendation.